# Como instalo a biblioteca discord.py no terminal unbutu?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Como instalo a biblioteca discord.py no terminal unbutu? O discord já está instalado, quero instalar agora o a biblioteca, pelo terminal.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install discord.py`

Comment: Eu estou instalando no Cloud9, porém "Já instalei e deu sucesso", mesmo assim ao tentar executar da erro no ansyc.

Comment: Consegui com o js mas os casos são diferentes

Comment: seguintes erros: Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/PyNaCl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-l36swjhs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/PyNaCl
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log